# I would like To Delete All Directories That are Older Than 5 Minutes?

Tags: php, timer, directory, delete-directory

So here comes the tricky part. There are specifically two Sub directories (the sub-directories also some contain file) in every Directory named lib and vendor. So when I used to have specific Dir name I used to use this

```
<?php 
$dir = $_GET['fname'];
array_map('unlink', glob("$dir/lib/*.*"));
rmdir("$dir/lib");
array_map('unlink', glob("$dir/vendor/*.*"));
rmdir("$dir/vendor");
array_map('unlink', glob("$dir/*.*"));
rmdir($dir);`
```

So I used to have a specific directory name. but now i want to change this.
So whenever a user is redirected to my script

It should delete all the directories that are older that 5 min. Only
    directories.

All the directories contain only and only 2 sub-directories named
    lib and vendor.They Should be deleted too.

These Three Directories Shouldn't be deleted project , images and
    assets.Except these all the directories should be deleted. Now

Please someone Help me out.

Comment: I'll make a guess... you are using folders and text files as your database correct? Might I suggest using a proper database? And if you don't have access to MySQL or if it's too complicated for you to set up on your server, you can literally use MySQLi, which is just 1 file designed to be very light weight database that's easy to setup and use, and has so many of the benefits of a proper database. After having set up MySQLi, you could run a simple command with SQL to delete all the rows 5 minutes old.

Comment: MySQLi is not SQLite. The answer above refers to SQLite.

Comment: And please be aware that this script easily can be hijacked to delete arbitrary folders. You shouldn't get the folder to delete from a user input.

Comment: The user doesn't gets to know anything. he sign ups. a folder is created with his username. he is only allowed to use the service for 5 min after that he redirected the home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this. First create a function to delete a directory

```
function deldirectory($dir){

$tfile = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($tfile,
             RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach($files as $file) {
    if ($file->isDir()){
        rmdir($file->getRealPath());
    } else {
        unlink($file->getRealPath());
    }
}
return rmdir($dir);
}
```

Call that function in foreach loop to check and delete the folder that are more then 5 minutes

```
foreach ($folders as $f){
    $lastmodified = filemtime($f);
    $farray = array("project","images","assets");//These folders are ignored
    $file_life = 300;
    if((time() - $lastmodified >= $file_life) && !in_array($f, $farray)){
       deldirectory($f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Amit, Unfortunately when i go to mydomainname.com/thescript.php , it just echoes out the whole code

Comment: Didnt you add <?php tag. Can you put that script here?

Comment: Nope.Its giving me this error -- Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/a3839924/public_html/tester.php on line 3

Comment: Can you paste the whole code. Then only i will be able to check it. Or you can use pastebin for that. http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Before using $folders you have to define it. $folders is an array of directory path which needs to be deleted. You have to provide the directory path. Like $folders = array("/var/www/yourwebsite/somedir","/var/www/yourwebsite/somedir2");

Comment: How do define $folder, i means everything's(folders) in public_html. Should i use this $folders = getcwd(); ?

Comment: after using $folders = getcwd(); i am still getting the same error.

Comment: getcwd(); is not an array and foreach requires an array. So you do like this $base_path = getcwd(); $folders = array($base_path); and the folders that you want to exclude you can do like this $farray = array($base_path."/project",$base_path."/images",$base_path."/assets");